# WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2058' ('MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR')

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am on websphere v7.0 and websphere mq 6. while trying to connect to queue manager through websphere console i am getting compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2058' error.The queue manager with the same is available on the mq server with the server channel defined.

Any help much Appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion would be to try connecting to queue manager using WMQ sample application from the machine where WebSphere 7.0 is running. Try to use amqsputc sample and see if you are able to put messages. You have to set MQSERVER environment variable and then use the sample. The command on Windows command prompt "set MQSERVER=<server conn channel name>/TCP/<hostname(port)>. Then do amqsputc SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE <qmgr name>. See if this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR (2058) is a generic error (This has been improved in the latest version of wmq).  There could be a problem with the host name or its resolution, the port or even the channel name or qmgr name.  Look closely for errors.  Is there anything reported in /var/mqm/errors on the websphere 7 server?

Answer (score 2):

If you are making use of a Client Channel Definition Table (CCDT) then this can imply that the queue manager name you used on MQCONN in your application, has not been found as QMNAME on any CLNTCONN channel in your CCDT. This can sometimes just mean that the CCDT has not been found at all.

Of course, sometimes this all just means that you meant to set MQSERVER to something and your forgot, so then the MQ Client goes looking for a CCDT instead and doesn't find one of those either.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error. Couple of things to try based on my debugging session.

1. Check QueueManager name. Note that it is case-sensitive. I had it in lower case in my python script. As soon as I put QueueManager name in capital letters. It worked.
2. Check if Queue host name is mentioned correctly. Queue manager name and Queue host name are different.
3. Check if you are able to telnet host on the port you are trying to access queue.
4. Restart Queue Manager.
5. Restart app server from where you are trying to connect.
6. Check if connection channel is mentioned correctly.
7. Check if queue name or queue Alias name are mentioned correctly.